# React post method not working with fetch method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mern

I made an API from my backend and it's properly working with postmen and if I try with my react app then its shows `404 error`. I also `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in `package.json` file.
When I try the same code 1st time then it's working properly but now it's not working.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({
    email: "",
    number: "",
  });

  let name, value;
  const handleInputs = (e) => {
    name = e.target.name;
    value = e.target.value;

    setUserLogin({ ...userLogin, [name]: value });
  };

  const postData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, number } = userLogin;
    console.log(userLogin);
    const loginRes = await fetch("/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, number }),
    });

    const data = await loginRes.json();
    if ((data.status === 422) | !data) {
      window.alert("invalid data");
      console.log("invalid data ");
    } else {
      window.alert("Data svae success!");
      console.log("Data svae success!");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form method="POST">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            value={userLogin.email}
            onChange={handleInputs}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Mobile</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="number"
            id="number"
            value={userLogin.number}
            onChange={handleInputs}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="register"
            name="signup"
            id="signup"
            onClick={postData}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Ignore this
I made an API from my backend and it's properly working with postmen and if I try with my react app then its shows `404 error`. I also `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in `package.json` file.
When I try the same code 1st time then it's working properly but now it's not working.
here is my code

Comment: If your url is right, than this may be a cors error. 
Best way to fix cors error allow origin that you are trying to access backend. Maybe you should share error message too

Comment: no there is no cors error

Comment: is your fetch URL is correct? I mean does not be look like "http://localhost:5000/login" or something like that? maybe this link helps you. https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/02/01/react-fetch-http-post-request-examples

Comment: no, it's only localhost:5000